# Let $Y$ have the Cauchy distribution, $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{1+y^2},\;-\infty<y<\infty$

Tags: probability-distributions, cauchy-sequences

(a) Show that $F_Y(y)=\tan^{-1}(y)$

I tried to use the usual method but quickly realized that it doesn't work.  I have been working other angles for hours and now I'm just stuck.

$F_Y=P(Y\leq y)$
$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{y}f_Y(t)dt$
$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{y}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$
$=[\tan^{-1}(t)]_{-\infty}^{y}$
$=\tan^{-1}(y)+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Obviously, this solution doesn't work.  I was thinking that there must be a transformation, $Y=g(X)$ on a standard Cauchy r.v., $X \sim$ Cauchy(0,1) with pdf $\;f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$, so that I can get the pdf of $Y$ as stated in the problem.

EDIT 1:
I figured if I could get limits on $y$ such that $\int f_Y=1$ then I'd have something. So I got

$1=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$
$=[\tan^{-1}(t)]_{-\infty}^{\alpha}$
$=\tan^{-1}(\alpha)+\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\Rightarrow \alpha=\tan(1-\frac{\pi}{2})$

So know I think I can say that $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{1+y^2},\;-\infty < y \leq \tan(1-\frac{\pi}{2})$

But now what...

EDIT 2:
By suggestions, I made the transformation $Y=g(x)=\frac{X}{\pi}$.

$\Rightarrow g^{-1}(y)=y\pi\;$ and $\;|J|=\pi$ so that

$f_Y=f_X(g^{-1}(y))|J|=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{y}{1/\pi})^2}$

But I'm still not sure how to get to $\;F_Y(y)=\tan^{-1}(y)$

EDIT 3:
I'm pretty sure that I am somehow supposed to use the theorem stating that if $X$ is a continuous r.v. with cdf $F_X$, then a r.v. $Y=F_X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, ie. $Y\sim Uniform(0,1)$. ([probability integral transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform))

So if $X \sim$ Cauchy$(0,1)$ and $Y=F_X=\frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(x)+\frac{1}{2}$, then $g^{-1}(y)=\tan(\pi(y-\frac{1}{2}))$.  This inverse function is so similar to the value of the upper limit that makes $\int_{-\infty}^{\tan(\pi(1-\frac{1}{2})}\frac{1}{1+y^2}=1$, that I feel the answer must be close.

Comment: Firstly, $\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}$ is not a probability density function, since its integral is $\pi$, not $1$. That is repaired by normalising with the factor $1/\pi$. Secondly, your calculation is correct, the given formula is wrong.

Comment: Daniel, I considered this many times, but I'm assuming it's not a typo since this book is in it's second edition. I've added some further work addressing your thoughts.

Comment: Tell you what: not all mistakes get caught between the first and second edition.

Comment: There is no way the book is right on this. If $F_Y$ is the cdf, then $F_Y(-\infty)$ must be 0 and $F(\infty)=1$, which is clearly false. There are multiple typos in the book.

Comment: I concur with the other commenters. It's a typo.

Comment: I agree, it's a typo. I looked at the previous edition, and this question wasn't included in the chapter, so it's not as unlikely to be a typo than I thought. So how should I edit this in case another person runs across the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

The book is wrong.  This is just the usual Cauchy distribution.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: But it is. These are very serious typos so you could consider reading another book

Answer (score 0):

Seems the density function should be normalized by $\pi$.

Comment: Ok. So went with this suggestion, but I don't end up with the right pdf. See above.